# calling a controller action with argument from rack middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

Is there a way I could pass an argument to a controller action call from middleware?

This is the action in controller code

```
# in my_controller.rb
# 
def print_name(name)
    render :text => "Hello, #{name}!"
end
```

Here's the code from my middleware that calls this action

```
# in middleware
#
def call(env)
  env['action_controller.instance'].class.action(:print_name).call(env)
end
```

This of course raises `ArgumentError`.

I'm unaware how can I pass an argument to `action` call. Here's the source:

```
# in action_pack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb
#
def self.action(name, klass = ActionDispatch::Request)
      middleware_stack.build(name.to_s) do |env|
        new.dispatch(name, klass.new(env))
      end
end
```

As you can see, it returns a rack endpoint from provided controller action. I see no way I could pass an argument here.

I ended up changing the controller dynamically with `class_eval` and then calling the controller method from that proxy method.

```
# in middleware
#
def define_proxy_method(klass)
      klass.class_eval do
            def call_the_real_method
              print_name(request.env['fake_attribute'])
            end
      end
 end

def call(env)
  define_proxy_method(env['action_controller.instance'].class)
  env['fake_attrbute'] = "Yukihiro"
  env['action_controller.instance'].class.action(:call_the_real_method).call(env)
end
```

This seems dirty and I would like to know of a better way. Thanks.

Comment: There's got to be a better approach to whatever you're trying to do. If you could provide more context to what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, there's probably a much less hacky solution.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect to a specific controller action after the exception has been thrown. Basically it's a [fix](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/commit/e13041bf9c69527b9bb34043617e52b6c7615657) for the airbrake gem. It was difficult enough to find the example of calling the controller method from the middleware. Thanks for the comment, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to put arguments on your action.  Middleware should only interact with the request environment, not try to call into the controller directly.

You can pass the same value in the params hash:

```
# middleware
#
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  request['name'] = get_name
end
```

and read from the params hash in the controller:

```
# my_controller.rb
# 
def print_name
    render :text => "Hello, #{params['name']}!"
end
```

Comment: yeah, I noticed it's the wrong way of doing it. it was implemented like this for rails 2.x, since it had a `rescue_action_in_public(exception)` in `ActionController` defined, and this method was aliasing it. I was trying to implement the same behavior for rails 3.x, without altering the method call. thanks for your answer though -> accept, upvote and bounty :)

Comment: Thanks.  You're welcome to e-mail me at winfield.peterson on gmail or gchat to talk further.  You might be able to extract your exception handling/reporting into a helper class and use it in both the Middleware and the Controllers.  If it has controller-specific redirect logic or other stuff you could put that in a block?  Happy to close the loop on a complete solution.